# Что такое перечислимые и не перечислимые свойства?

Tags: javascript

Объясните, пожалуйста, что такое перечислимые свойства и неперечислимые? Столкнулся с ними здесь:

> Метод `propertyIsEnumerable()` накладывает дополнительные ограничения по
>   сравнению с `hasOwnProperty()`. Он возвращает `true`, только если
>   указанное свойство является собственным  свойством, атрибут `enumerable`
>   которого имеет значение `true`. Свойства встроенных объектов не являются
>   перечислимыми. Свойства, созданные обычной программой на языке
>   JavaScript, являются  перечислимыми, если не был использован один из
>   методов ECMAScript 5, представленных ниже, которые  делают свойства
>   неперечислимыми.
>
> ```
> var o = inherit({ y: 2 });
> o.x = 1;
> o.propertyIsEnumerable("x"); // true: o имеет собств. перечислимое свойство x 
> o.propertyIsEnumerable("y"); // false: y - унаследованное свойство, не собств.
> Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable("toString");  //  false:  неперечислимое
> ```
>
> *(c) Дэвид Флэнаган "JavaScript. Подробное руководство", 6-е издание, стр. 148*

Из этих строк выходит что:

- Неперечислимые свойства - это свойства встроенных объектов. Тут
  следует уточнить что такое встроенные объекты: это объекты `Array`,
  `Boolean`, `Date`, `Error`, `Function`, `Global`, `JSON`, `Math`,
  `Number`, `Object`, `RegExp` и `String`.
- Перечислимые свойства - это свойства созданные обычной программой.
  Конкретно из данного контекста получается - свойства, присвоенные
  объекту оператором присваивания `=`, без всякого наследования
  (собственные свойства):

  ```
    o.x = 1  // Объекту "o" присвоенно свойство "x" со значеним "1"
  ```

  т.е. неперечислимым свойство будет в случае наследования, и если это
  свойство встроенного объекта.

Пока писал, как будто бы разобрался. Поправьте меня, если ошибаюсь.

Comment: В общем да, если свойство наследовано, либо от встроенное - оно не перечислимо. Плюс к этому свойство явно можно сделать не перечислимым: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968962/hasownproperty-vs-propertyisenumerable   А книга у вас хорошая. И кто сказал, что будет легко. программирование и верстка совершенно разные вещи. Да и JS далеко не самый простой язык. И глубокое понимание после одной книги вряд ли придет. тут опыт нужен. Понимание переменных и функций уже достаточно что бы делать базовые вещи, которые и надо уже пробовать делать

Answer (score 2):

Есть цикл for each , который позволяет в цикле перебрать все свойстве объекта и соответственно дальше с ними уже что-то делать. Так вот , такое можно делать только с перечисляемыми свойствами объекта.
Дэвид Флэнаган JavaScript. Подробное руководство, 6-е издание - считается лучшей книгой по JS.Могу вам посоветовать codeacademy. Там есть отличные курсы по js. На практике вы должны все увидеть.

Comment: все-таки `for..in`

Answer (score 0):

Сложный учебник? - пройдите этот: https://learn.javascript.ru/

А насчёт вашего вопроса, те свойства являются не перебираемыми, которые в прототипе. Но можно задать отдельные параметры, с помощью `Object.defineProperty`.
Подробнее можно почитать об этом здесь:
https://learn.javascript.ru/descriptors-getters-setters

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.